# Remove Items Broken Links due to the item being unkown

Tags: powershell-extensions

Is it possible to removed broken links using sitecore powershell.
I checked the items link in the Navigation > Links and some of them has "Not found: master {GUID}".

[image]

Here is the sample code I have that will fetch the links but it will an error because the linkedItem doesn't exist.

```
$page = Get-Item -Path $SearchParentPath
$links = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $page -ItemLink

# Iterate through referring items
foreach ($link in $links) {
    $linkedItem = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore" -ID $link.SourceItemID
    if ($linkedItem -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "Broken Link $($link.SourceItemID)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SSE, if you wish to clear broken links, do check these links -https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11282/rebuilding-link-database-system-formatexception-unrecognized-guid-format  and   https://www.sitecorescrub.com/post/easy-fix-for-broken-sitecore-link-database

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `Get-Item`, use `Test-Path` command.

It will return either `true` or `false` depending on whether the item with given ID exists:

```
$page = Get-Item -Path $SearchParentPath
$links = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $page -ItemLink

# Iterate through referring items
foreach ($link in $links) {
    $exists = Test-Path $link.SourceItemID.ToString()
    if (!$exists) {
        Write-Host "Broken Link $($link.SourceItemID)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It removed the error but I am still not sure on how to remove the link itself.

I also tried looping the items from GetBrokenLinks.

Comment: There are multiple scenarios here. It can be a `LinkField` - the easiest would be to link to another item, e.g. to Home item or remove the link completely. It can be also a multi list so you would need to remove only single item from the list then.

Comment: Hello. I know this thread is kind of old, but have you managed to fix this Problem? I mean, how can i remove the link completely or link it to home?

Comment: Just use `Rebuild Link Database` from `Control Panel`